# Project creation of silk4j getting "interface SpringProxy is not visible from class loader"

Tags: java, silktest

I got the following error during the creation of a new Silk4J project in Eclipse.

> interface org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy is not visible from class loader

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your indirect dependencies are not imported you can add those explicitly in your POM and try again

```
<Import-Package>
    ...
    org.aopalliance.aop,
    org.springframework.aop,
    org.springframework.aop.framework,
    ...
</Import-Package>
```